# missing rosdeps for gtest and paramiko running OS: Arch

Tags: ros-comm, log4cxx, gtest, rosmake, archlinux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
I installed a new ARCH system and made a rosinstall for the full desktop. At the end I got an error message because the rosmake for ros and ros_comm did not work. Manually I started the rosmake ros and it worked, but not the ros_comm. After the PACKAGES zip (package found) the process runs into my editor with the pkgbuid for log4cxx. After leaving the editor it starts again with the packages and into the editor with the pkgbuild.
For a second try I only started make in the ros_comm directory. Without this, I can not start roscore.
Can someone help?

Uwe

rosmake ros_comm --rosdep-install
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['ros_comm']                                
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/thater/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110525-125759
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['ros_comm'] to:
['message_filters', 'cpp_common', 'xmlrpcpp', 'roswtf', 'rostime', 'rosgraph_msgs', 'std_srvs', 'std_msgs', 'rospy', 'roslisp', 'roscpp_traits', 'roscpp', 'roscpp_serialization', 'topic_tools', 'roslaunch', 'rosbag', 'rosout', 'rosmsg', 'rosnode', 'rosbagmigration', 'rosconsole', 'rosgraph', 'rosservice', 'rosparam', 'rostest', 'rostopic', 'rosrecord', 'rosmaster', 'test_roscpp_serialization_perf', 'test_rosmaster', 'test_rosbag', 'test_rospy', 'test_rosmsg', 'test_rosnode', 'test_roscpp', 'test_roslib_comm', 'test_crosspackage', 'test_roscpp_serialization', 'test_ros', 'test_rostest', 'test_rostopic', 'test_roslaunch', 'test_topic_tools', 'test_rosgraph', 'test_rosservice', 'test_rosparam', 'test_roswtf', 'perf_roscpp', 'test_rostime', 'roscore_migration_rules']
[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package message_filters on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package message_filters on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package roswtf on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package roswtf on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package topic_tools on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package topic_tools on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package roslaunch on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package rosbag on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package rosbag on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package rosmsg on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package rosmsg on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package rosbagmigration on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package rosbagmigration on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package rosservice on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package rosservice on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package rostest on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package rostest on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package rostopic on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package rostopic on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package rosrecord on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package rosrecord on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package test_rosmaster on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package test_rosmaster on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package test_rosbag on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package test_rosbag on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package test_rospy on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package test_rospy on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package test_rosmsg on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package test_rosmsg on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package test_rosnode on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package test_rosnode on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package test_roscpp on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package test_roscpp on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package test_roslib_comm on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package test_ros on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package test_ros on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package test_rostest on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package test_rostest on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package test_rostopic on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package test_rostopic on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package test_roslaunch on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package test_roslaunch on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package test_topic_tools on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package test_topic_tools on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package test_rosgraph on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package test_rosgraph on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package test_rosservice on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package test_rosservice on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package test_rosparam on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package test_rosparam on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package test_roswtf on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package test_roswtf on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep gtest for package roscore_migration_rules on OS:arch version:
Failed to find rosdep paramiko for package roscore_migration_rules on OS:arch version:
WARNING: Rosdeps [u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko', u'gtest', u'paramiko'] could not be resolved
rosdep executing this script:
{{{
set -o errexit
#Packages
sudo pacman -Sy --needed pil python-numpy pkgconfig
if ! pacman -Q log4cxx; then yaourt -S log4cxx; fi


if ! pacman -Q libyaml python-yaml; then yaourt -S libyaml python-yaml; fi

}}}
Passwort: 
:: Synchronisiere Paketdatenbanken...
 core ist aktuell
 extra ist aktuell
 community ist aktuell
 archlinuxfr ist aktuell
Warnung: python-imaging-1.1.7-3 ist aktuell -- Überspringe
Warnung: python2-numpy-1.5.1-2 ist aktuell -- Überspringe
Warnung: pkg-config-0.25-3 ist aktuell -- Überspringe
 Es gibt nichts zu tun



First Submitted: Sat, 31 Mar 2007 03:35:18 +0000    
log4cxx 0.10.0-2 
( Unsupported package: Potentially dangerous ! )

 - apr-util (already installed)
 - libxml2 (already installed)
 - libtool (already installed)
 - gzip (already installed)
 - sed (already installed)
 - autoconf (package found)
 - automake (package found)
 - patch (package found)
 - zip (package found)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thater/ros/ros/bin/rosmake", line 65, in 
    if rma.main():
  File "/home/thater/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/rosmake.py", line 848, in main
    self.rosdep_install_result = self.install_rosdeps(buildable_packages, options.rosdep_yes)
  File "/home/thater/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/rosmake.py", line 310, in install_rosdeps
    error = r.install(include_duplicates=False, default_yes=default_yes)
  File "/home/thater/ros/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/core.py", line 392, in install
    (out, err) = p.communicate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 735, in communicate
    stderr = self.stderr.read()
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thater/ros/ros/bin/rosmake", line 65, in 
    if rma.main():
  File "/home/thater/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/rosmake.py", line 848, in main
    self.rosdep_install_result = self.install_rosdeps(buildable_packages, options.rosdep_yes)
  File "/home/thater/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/rosmake.py", line 310, in install_rosdeps
    error = r.install(include_duplicates=False, default_yes=default_yes)
  File "/home/thater/ros/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/core.py", line 392, in install
    (out, err) = p.communicate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 735, in communicate
    stderr = self.stderr.read()
KeyboardInterrupt
[thater@myhost ~]$ roscd ros_comm
[thater@myhost ros_comm]$ make
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning: The variable, 'CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE', specified manually, was not used during the generation.
-- Build files have been written to: /home/thater/ros/ros_comm/build
--#cd build && make 
[thater@myhost ros_comm]$ roscore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thater/ros/ros/bin/roscore", line 34, in 
    from ros import roslaunch
  File "/home/thater/ros/ros/core/roslib/src/ros/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    return __import__(name)
  File "/home/thater/ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 53, in 
    from roslaunch.scriptapi import ROSLaunch
  File "/home/thater/ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/scriptapi.py", line 42, in 
    import roslaunch.parent
  File "/home/thater/ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/parent.py", line 55, in 
    import roslaunch.server
  File "/home/thater/ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/server.py", line 70, in 
    from rosgraph_msgs.msg import Log
ImportError: No module named rosgraph_msgs.msg





---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10055/missing-rosdeps-for-gtest-and-paramiko-running-os:-arch/) by [uwe](https://answers.ros.org/users/590/uwe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-05-24


Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to create a rosdep rule to install paramiko and gtest on arch and add it to the rosdep.yaml file. There's a [tutorial for this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep/Tutorials/Add%20new%20OS%20to%20rosdep.yaml)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1